# Non-static method UFactory::getModuleAlias() should not be called statically Uniprogy Yii

Tags: php, yii, static-methods

I have migrated my App and I have problem Non-static method:

```
Error 500
Non-static method UFactory::getModuleAlias() should not be called statically
```

I have changed the debug to true:

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

then I got an error

> Non-static method UFactory::getModuleAlias() should not be called
> statically
>
> /home/tradertrga/www/_CRM/framework/uniprogy/framework/base/UFactory.php(88)

```
076             
077             $alias = '.'.rtrim($alias,'.');
078             $paths = explode('.',substr($alias,0,strrpos($alias,'.')));
079             $itemName = substr($alias,strrpos($alias,'.')+1);
080             
081             $className = '';
082             
083             $id = explode('/',$module->getId());
084             $id = implode('',array_map('ucfirst',$id));
085             $className = $id . $className;
086             
087             $path = 'application.modules.'
088                 . str_replace('.','.modules.',self::getModuleAlias($module)).'.'.$type;
089             if(count($paths))
090             {
091                 $path.= implode('.', $paths);
092                 $className.= implode('', array_map('ucfirst',$paths));
093             }
094             $letter = strtoupper(substr($type,0,1));
095             $path.= '.'.$letter.$className.ucfirst($itemName);
096             
097             self::saveToCache($key,array('module' => self::getModuleAlias($module),
098                 'path' => $path));
099         }
```

Comment: https://github.com/khoa-le/uniprogy/blob/master/framework/uniprogy/framework/base/UFactory.php#L191 seems like you got old version or smthing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellon,

I have solved this Problem only by adding this line of Code in index.php.

```
error_reporting(E_NONE);
```

Thank You

Comment: Turning off error reporting is not a "solution" -- it is hiding the problem.